# How to get the number of combined unique values for two columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a pandas data frame with 2 columns.

I want to count the distinct or unique values for both columns - i.e `col1` having 1,3 and `col2` having 2,4 (`1` was already counted in `col1`).  My final output should be 4.

How can I achieve this?

```
tr=pd.DataFrame({"Col1":[1,1,1,1,3,3],"Col2":[1,2,2,2,4,4]})
print (tr)
```

Comment: Stack and nunique, tr.stack().nunique()

Comment: You have these steps: (1) collect all values from each column; (2) combine those into a single list; (3) remove duplicates; (4) report the size of the resulting structure.  Each of these is available through on-line search; we expect you to make this attempt before posting here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per @Vaishali's comment, you need:

```
import pandas as pd

tr = pd.DataFrame({"Col1":[1,1,1,1,3,3],"Col2":[1,2,2,2,4,4]})

Out = tr.stack().nunique()
print(Out)
4
```